# Sphinx search with any "symbol" breaks the search engine?

Tags: search, unicode, utf-8, lucene, sphinx

For some reason, when I type a symbol anywhere in the query,

`. ! ^ ,` or anything else, the search engine breaks.

But when I type in "#" , the search engine does not break.

That's because I modified the charset to deal with `#hashtag`s.

```
charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+23, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F
```

How can I fix this so that I could include other symbols in the query as well as make the hashtag work? (Right now the hashtag works wonders, and sphinx treats it as a normal keyword)

By the way, the unicode for hashtag is "U+0023"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about `.` and `,` (Sphinx specific?), but `!` and `^` (among others, that is `+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \`) are Lucene special characters and you need to [escape them](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html). See *Escaping Special Characters* at the bottom of the page.